# Differentiability/continuity of stabilizing solution to algebraic Riccati equation with respect to matrix parameters

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization

When solving the LQR problem to find the optimal feedback matrix $K^*$, i.e. solving
\begin{align*}
\min_K &\int_0^\infty \left(x^TQx + u^TRu\right)dt,\\
\text{s.t. }&\dot{x} = Ax+Bu,\\
&u=-Kx,
\end{align*}
where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $u\in\mathbb{R}^q$, $A,B,Q,R,K$, are real and of appropriate dimension, it is well-known that to solve this problem, the solution the algebraic Riccati equation can be used:
$$A^TP+PA-PBR^{-1}B^TP = -Q,$$
where, for simplicity, say $R\succ 0$, $Q\succ 0$. Now, if $A,B$ are stabilizable, the unique, stabilizing, symmetric and positive-definite solution $P^*$ is unique (correct me if I'm wrong). Let's say that the set of possible stabilizing solutions for given $Q,R$ to the Riccati equation is denoted by $\mathcal{P}^*(Q,R)$.

Ultimately, my goal is to check whether the gradient of the unique stabilizing solution with respect to $Q,R$ exists, and if so, compute it at a given $Q,R$. From what I've read about convex, parametric optimization problems (since, e.g., [this paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1166522?casa_token=TQjQn0vxeigAAAAA:qz-yR1Pj44X_zMCjJcvs5nDi7exB-zXzfzHz9l5Lf4qiCRNLYW-vi8Hm6mwnFl2xH-dYqf3lIg) shows that finding the unique, stabilizing solution $P^*$ can also be formulated as an SDP problem), this first requires that the solution set $\mathcal{P}^*(Q,R)$ is a singleton, i.e., $\mathcal{P}^*(Q,R) = \{P^*(Q,R)\}$.

Now, I know that for a given $Q,R$, there exists a unique solution $P^*$, so that should mean that  indeed $\mathcal{P}^*(Q,R) = \{P^*(Q,R)\}$. So, it remains to be seen whether $P^*(Q,R)$ is differentiable with respect to $Q,R$.

I checked different sources ([1](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF01581237.pdf),[2](http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2018/04/6587.pdf)) on the topic; however, most of them include a multitude of assumptions which are either not satisified for my problem or seem quite hard to verify. Furthermore, I feel like the fact that I already know that my solution set is a singleton should simply the answer to the question.

Therefore, I am wondering whether for this specific problem, there is a more straighforward way to see whether $\nabla_{Q,R} P^*(Q,R)$ exists or not.

Any hints or corrections are very much appreciated

Comment: This looks like it can be proved with the implicit function theorem. Have you tried that route already? Or is yours a case where the Jacobian $(A-BR^{-1}B^TP)^T \otimes I + I \otimes (A-BR^{-1}B^TP)^T$ is singular?

Comment: This would, however, only allow me to check if the gradient for a specific $Q,R$, and corresponding $P^*$ exists, correct (and compute it if so)? Ideally, I would like a statement that says something about differentiability for any $Q,R$. Or do you think this is too ambitious? In any case, thanks, this was already helpful!

Comment: If I am not mistaken, with the implicit function theorem you can (1) prove that the gradient exists whenever the Jacobian is invertible (i.e., whenever the feedback is truly stabilizing without eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, because of properties of the Kronecker sum/product) (2) have a closed-formula for that gradient, based on either inverting a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix built with Kronecker products, or solving a $n\times n$ Lyapunov equation.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that $A-BR^{-1}B^TP = A-BK = A_{cl}$ at first, and since it is stabilizing, all eigenvalues are negative and thus $A_{cl}$ is invertible. Thank you very much for clarifying!